# Semantic Search in SQL - SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE not found

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2012

Trying to use Semantic search in SQL Server 2012, have got everything set up described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509085.aspx)

When i run the following query on my database (have changed the columns etc, just including for thoroughness)

```
  SELECT * FROM SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE(Recruitment.CandidateCv,cv)
```

or any of the Semantic Search functions, i get 'not found' error.

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE'.
```

I must be missing some config setting or something, please help.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509095.aspx), I think you might miss some parameters.

> ```
> Transact-SQL
> ```
>
> SEMANTICSIMILARITYDETAILSTABLE 
>       (
>       table,
>       source_column,
>       source_key,
>       matched_column,
>       matched_key
>       )

You can try this [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492062.aspx) : )